# Dedicated or remap 'calculator' button on my keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, remap, power-toys

Win10

I have a keyboard which has a dedicated 'calculator' button on my keyboard that brings up the Windows calculator up.
Its just to the right of the F12 key, and just above the backspace key.
This button is a pain in the arse when I am typing text which I do all the time.
My goal is to deactivate this key, or map it to something benign.

My attempt involves the installation of Windows PowerToys which contains a keyboard manager. I am hoping to remap or deactivate this key in this tool, but I need to identify this key in a list of keys, but I cannot find it.

The list does show what appears to be the whole list of VK numbers (Virtual keyboard)
Could this be a way to point to the calculator key? if so how do I find the right VK number for this key?

Alternatively, does anyone else know of how a key on a keyboard can be deactivated without the use of superglue?

many thanks everyone